# Apache Flink: Best practice for a pipeline with large state

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

### Background

I want to move a job that running on DB to Flink to make the system works more "real time".
This job will re-calculate the "state" of all accounts for each 10 seconds and if this value met some conditions we will notify the user about it.
The "state" of an account is calculate based on the number of stocks they have and the current price of these stocks.

### My solution

My idea is to create a pipeline with these inputs:

- BeginStream: The begin of day data (initial data): The stock price from the last day, the number of stock of each account. The data may read from DB tables or loading from a Kafka topic.
- PriceStream: A Kafka topic with each message contains the price of a stock like this:
  {"name":"stockName", "price": currentPrice}
- StockStream: A Kafka topic with each message contains the number of stock that account buy or sell (positive or negative number), like this:
  {"account": accountNumber, "stock": "stockName", "quantity": changingNumber}

My solution: Joining BeginStream with StockStream and then joining with PriceStream (all will be keyBy StockName) and for doing calculation for each stock of BeginStream, I'll create a ListState called stockStates which contains the info about: number of stock and current price.

For each event from StockStream and PriceStream, I'll update the stockStates and then calculate the "state". And if this value met some conditions, we will send a message to other Kafka topic and remove this account from this ListState

```
BeginStream
  .keyby(StockName)
  .connect(
      StockStream.
        .keyby(StockName))
  .flatMap(new EnrichmentFucntion())
...
  .connect(
      PriceStream.
        .keyby(StockName))
  .flatMap(new EnrichmentFucntion())
```

The system contains about 500.000 accounts, 1.000 stocks and each account hold 10-20 stocks, the throughput of PriceStream and StockStream is about 1.000 messages/second.

### Question

I'm new with Flink and therefore I'm not so sure whether my solution is a good approach ? Are there any design pattern for the similar problems ?
And with the number of about 1000 ListState(each list contains state for about 500.000*10/1000=5.000 account) should I use RocksDB for state storing ?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, your use case can be implemented in flink. RocksDB as a state backend is a good choice.